# URL encoding for Python OAuth2

Tags: python, oauth, urlencode

I am using %20 to encode a url using oauth2 for python.

It does not seem to work.  I see that it encodes %20 as %252B . Is there a way around?

Edited with example

```
import oauth2 as oauth
client = oauth.Client(consumer)
url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/search?Name=Julian'
method= 'GET'
response,content = client.request(url,method)
print content
```

The above code works.  If I try

```
Name=Julian%20Assange or 
Name=Julian+Assange,
```

it does not work. The %20 is encoded to %252B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a double quoting issue.

```
urllib2.quote('%')
'%25'
```

Can you try not encoding your url before giving it to oauth?

Comment: yeah looks like it.  I have a url and in place of space I manually type %20, if I type as space it does not work....

Comment: Can you post some example code? Does using a + for the space behave the same?